minipage customised in llncs doc class
I want to produce a 2x2 plot llncs class using minipage. But I do not want the Fig. X.... for all subplots. I want them for formatted like a.) Image 1, b.) Image 2.... And then 1 common, shared Fig. 1. Title
My code:
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption*{a.) Img 1 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:smf2016}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption*{b.) Img 2 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:geo-ori}
    \end{minipage}
    \vfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption*{c.) Img 3 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:geo-exp2}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption*{d.) Img 4 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:geo-exp3}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Just 1 common figure title (as Fig. 1. ).}
    \label{fig:overall}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Which produces:

Required Format:
 a.) Img 1       b.) Img 2
 
 c.) img 3       d.) Img 4
   Fig. 1. Figure Title.


You could use the subcaption package like this:
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{rightparens}{#2.)}
\subcaptionsetup[figure]{labelformat=rightparens}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{subcaptionblock}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Img 1 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:smf2016}
    \end{subcaptionblock}
    \hfill
    \begin{subcaptionblock}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Img 2 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:geo-ori}
    \end{subcaptionblock}
    \vfill
    \begin{subcaptionblock}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Img 3 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:geo-exp2}
    \end{subcaptionblock}
    \hfill
    \begin{subcaptionblock}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Img 4 (no Fig.)}
        \label{fig:geo-exp3}
    \end{subcaptionblock}
    \caption{Just 1 common figure title (as Fig. 1. ).}
    \label{fig:overall}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


